# Get error when trying to publish float64 arm message

Tags: ros, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Get an error(see below) when trying to publish a float64 arm command.

Using Ubuntu 12.04.1 Ros Hydro

source file:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <std_msgs/Float64.h>
#include "pub/ArmPan.h"

pub::ArmPan panmsg;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "pub");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher ArmPan_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Float64>("ArmPan/command", 1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    int count = 0;

    while(ros::ok())
    {
        panmsg.ArmPan = 1.0;
        ArmPan_pub.publish(panmsg);
        ros::spinOnce();
        loop_rate.sleep();
        ++count;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the file ArmPan.msg has one line:
float64 ArmPan

rosrun fails with this err:

```
[FATAL] Assertion failed
file = /opt/ros/hydro/include/ros/publisher.h
line 115
cond = impl_->md5sum == "*" || std::string(mt::md5sum<M>(message))
             == "*" || impl_->md5sum == mt::md5sum<M>(message)
Trying to publish message of type [pub/ArmPan] on a publisher with type [std_msgs/Float64]
```

if the message

```
rostopic pub -1 ArmPan/command std_msgs/Float64 1
```

is entered, it works.

This code worked in earlier versions of ROS but now fails with Hydro. Can you tell me why?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/168891/get-error-when-trying-to-publish-float64-arm-message/) by [garym](https://answers.ros.org/users/3471/garym/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-05-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem here is that you're advertising one type of message, and calling publish with a different type of message.

This only worked in older versions of ROS because there was a bug in the publisher that didn't check the data type on publish, and I guess you were able to get away with it because the serialized version of your message just happened to be the same as a std_msgs/Float64

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-05-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0